# what is the use of room in the in the render section?

Tags: django, django-models, django-views, django-forms, django-templates

***python Django framework
I can't understand what is the use of {'rooms':rooms}) in the render section please help i am just learning django

---

```
import imp
from django.shortcuts import render
from django.http import HttpResponse


rooms =[
    {'id':1, 'name':'learn python'},
    {'id':2, 'name':'learn html and javascript'},
    {'id':3, 'name':'at last learn django'},
]



# Create your views here.
def home(request):
    return render(request,'home.html',
                  **{'rooms':rooms})**


def room(request):
    return render(request,
                    'room.html')
```

Comment: This is how you send information from your view into your html template.  See https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.0/ref/templates/api/#rendering-a-context.  Now you do something like this in your template: <div>{{ room }}</div>, and use it as a variable.

Answer (score 0):

`{'rooms':rooms}` is a dictionary with key/value pair.

You send this key/value pair to *home.html* with this statement

```
return render(request,'home.html',
                  {'rooms':rooms})
```

Now inside *home.html*, you can access this dictionary with just the key `rooms`. For example,

*home.html*

```
<html>
  <head>
  </head>
  <body>
    {{ rooms }}
  </body>
</html>
```

It is not required that the key and value should be the same name. Instead of `{'rooms':rooms}`, you can also use `{'number_of_rooms':rooms}`. But then you have to access the value inside *home.html* using the key `number_of_rooms`

*home.html*

```
<html>
  <head>
  </head>
  <body>
    {{ number_of_rooms }}
  </body>
</html>
```